# waiting for an element while condition is still fullfilled

Tags: selenium

The wait helpers are very useful functions. But it seems they can wait only for an element to exist (Until...)
Is there a wait to say "wait while condition is still fullfilled" ?
Example, click some element and wait for some other element to disappear

Answer (score 1):

You can try (at least with Java, I'm not sure if it's in the other languages) is the ExpectedConditions.not the method, which you can wrap around another ExpectedConditions.

An example would be something like:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector('#loading-spinner'))));
```

or you can try

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector('#loading-content')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium in Java has

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

methods.
Selenium in Python has `invisibility_of_element_located` and `staleness_of` methods too.
So you can create a method clicking on some element and waiting for it to disappear, like this:

```
public void clickVisibleDisappear(By element){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element)).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
}
```

Or clicking on one element and waiting for some other element to disappear as you asked, like this:

```
public void clickVisibleDisappear(By element1, By element2){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element1)).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element2));
}
```